# How to Create WPMu New User?

Tags: multisite, user-registration

**Here is my problem:**

1. I had install WpMU(Wordpress Multisite) in my own server. I had install WPMU yourdomain.com/demo .
2. At the time of WPMU installation, I had only 1 user for access all sites under this main site (yourdomain.com/demo). This user can access all of the site under yourdomain.com/demo .
3. So my some site site URL was: 
       yourdomain.com/demo/site1 ,
       yourdomain.com/demo/site2,
    
       yourdomain.com/demo/site3,
       yourdomain.com/demo/site4 ,
       yourdomain.com/demo/site5
4. This Admin username was: user1
5. Then I had add a new user, which name was: user2
6. After that, I deleted user1 from PHPmy Admin
7. Now user2 can only access yourdomain.com/demo/ . But user2, can't access other sites from this site. As like: yourdomain.com/demo/site1 , yourdomain.com/demo/site2, yourdomain.com/demo/site3, yourdomain.com/demo/site4 , yourdomain.com/demo/site5

Please tell me, How user2 can access all of the sites in WPMU sites, as like yourdomain.com/demo/site1 , yourdomain.com/demo/site2, yourdomain.com/demo/site3, yourdomain.com/demo/site4 , yourdomain.com/demo/site5 ?

Waiting for Quick Solution.

Regards
  Sudipta

Comment: "Waiting for Quick Solution" Not going to happen. Please work on the format of your question. It is not reader friendly

Comment: First of all you should not delete users using phpMyAdmin.  You should be deleting users from WP admin consoles.  Second, did you give user2 Super Admin privileges before deleting user1?  And did you confirm user2 privileges?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give user2 Super Admin privileges by directly modifying the database.

Run this query in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_sitemeta where meta_key='site_admins';
```

This is an array of all your Super Admins.  It should return something like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:5:"user1";}
```

Note that 5 is the length of string 'user1'.  Here is an example modification to make 'username2' the Super Admin:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:9:"username2";}
```